# HBase Versioning: Use built-in system or custom timestamp management?

Tags: hbase, versioning

I am in the process of planning a versioned data store with HBase. In this case "versioned" means that **old data *never* gets deleted** and is retained **indefinitly** for auditing and analysis purposes. Most reads will still occur on the latest version.

HBase itself provides a versioning mechanism, but by default it keeps only the last X versions and discards everything else.

I have several concerns here:

1. What are the implications when increasing the maximum number of versions in HBase to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, in particular with respect to performance? Is HBase ready to handle this case, or is it discouraged?
2. Will (major) compactions respect the `max_versions` setting or will a major compaction always discard older row versions when using the HBase-internal versioning system? The documentation is not very specific here.
3. Given that the number of versions on a given key can grow to very large numbers, would it be better to ignore the built-in versioning system and implement it via combined row-keys?